# Some formulas and functions

Tags: ocaml

So, I've got to write a recursive function which will count the number of "1"'s are in an any given number. For this part, I managed to create the function which converts a decimal to binary :

```
let rec f dec =
if dec = 0 then 0
else dec mod 2 + 10 *f(dec/2)
;;
```

but I've got no idea how to make the program check each digit and even count the wanted ones.

And I have to write a function which has to calculate the sum of the 1/(n!) series. Again, I tried for hours, but the best I could do was :

```
let rec e n =
if n <= 1. then 1.
else 1./.(n*.e(n-.1.)) +. (e(n-.1.))
;;
```

which doesn't work the right way cause I guess the formula isn't right.

Comment: Hey @Nicoleta. You really shouldn't ask multiple questions in the same post, as it works really poorly with the Q&A format of Stack Overflow. Since you've already gotten an answer which addresses both questions I won't remove the second one, but please post questions separately in the future.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, you probably want to generate a list of bits in a first time rather than an integer. It should make further bit manipulation easier to handle.

For the second question, you should write a separate factorial function first and use it in your definition of `e`. Currently, you are mixing the sum computation and the factorial computation.

Comment: Could you give an advice in how can I translate that into syntax?

Comment: Which part are you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the `1` of a binary number:

```
let rec count_1 n =
  if n=0 then 0
  else
    (if n mod 2 = 1 then 1 else 0) + count_1 (n/2)
```

For the sum of 1 / n! :

```
let f n =
  let inv_fact = ref 1.0 in
  let sum = ref 0. in
  for i=1 to n do
    inv_fact := !inv_fact /. (Float.of_int i);
    sum := !sum +. !inv_fact
  done;
  !sum
```

We could also be less imperative:

```
let my_f n = 
  let rec f n max inv_fact =
    if n>max then 0.
    else
      let inv_fact' = inv_fact /. (Float.of_int n) in
        inv_fact' +. f (n+1) max inv_fact'
  in f 1 n 1.
```

With your `e` function, we don't know if it should return the inversed factorial (you use `e(n-.1.)`or the sum).